# Can not open .txt file in Python. Using Enthought Canopy Editor in Windows 10

Tags: python

First, coding in Python 2.7.11 using Enthought Canopy editor in Windows 10.  At this point I'm embarrassed to ask this, but I'm going out of my mind.  All I want to do is open a text file.  This is the code I am trying to use

```
import os 

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
abs_path = os.path.join(script_dir,"romeo.txt")

print os.getcwd()
print abs_path

if os.path.isfile(abs_path):
     tfile = open(abs_path) 
else:
     print "That is not a valid filename."
```

The output from both os.getcwd() and abs_path are what I want and expect them to be.  I promise there is a text file called "romeo.txt" in exactly the place where I want it.  But isfile does not return true.  I am so confused at this point.  Please help.

Comment: if `os.path.isfile(abs_path)` says there's no file there, then it's not a *file*. It could be a directory or a symlink, or even a shortcut when it comes to windows. If you open up notepad.txt and copy the `abs_path` and try to open that file, can you open that file?

Comment: Does this code run *outside* the editor?

Comment: Why even mess with these `os.path.*`? Just `open("romeo.txt")`, that's all.

Comment: worked for me in python 2.7 shell with file in same directory

Comment: @ForceBru that will only work if `romeo.txt` is in the directory you're running in. `python /path/to/my/program.py` won't necessarily have the text file

Comment: also what's the output of `print os.listdir(script_dir)`?

Comment: The answer to the print os.listdir(script_dir) question is: [u'hello_world.py', u'mbox_short.txt.txt', u'romeo.txt.txt', u'romeo_parse.py', u'shout.py'].  And that explains the dilemma.  I was saving the files in Windows with the file type  tacked on.  Thank you so much Wayne :)